# Chrome [v44] - Bug em tabelas dentro de uma div com overflow

Tags: css, google-chrome, tabela-html

Na nova versão do Chrome (versão 44) as tabelas não estão se comportando da mesma forma com que as outras versões do mesmo se comportavam.

Esperado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Ao redimensionar a tela, o navegador calcula a largura de cada `td` ajustando sua largura para conter o conteúdo e ao mesmo tempo não estourar a largura total da tela (ou do elemento em que está inserida) até o momento em que não é mais possível quebrar o conteúdo em várias linhas e a tabela ultrapassa a largura do elemento pai.

No entanto, na nova versão, o chrome para de considerar a largura do elemento pai antes do esperado. Analisando o exemplo do resultado obtido, pode-se perceber que ainda é possível quebrar o conteúdo da coluna 3 em linhas, ou seja, diminuir a largura da mesma para que não seja necessário utilizar o scroll.

[JSFiddle da tabela.](https://jsfiddle.net/oeslei/av3uk1at/)

Até o momento, a única forma que encontrei de contornar este problema é setar a largura das `td`s para `1%`. Porém, desta forma, todas as `td`s ficam com o mesmo tamanho, independente de seu conteúdo. Setar a largura de cada `td` também seria inviável.

Alguém possui uma solução para o problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É um bug conhecido e reportado:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=512872

O *merge* para o trunk principal do projeto já foi solicitado.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Não consegui emular seu erro, então eu não posso garantir que essa resposta ajude.</sup>

### Trabalhando com Viewport

Você deve inserir a meta tag viewport no `<head>` do seu documento

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
```

Essa tag informa ao browser que o *viewport* é do tamanho da tela do usuário e a escala inicial é 1.

### Usando unidade de tamanho relativo do viewport (vw e vh)

`vw` e `vh` são novas unidades no [CSS3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths) que se baseia no tamanho do viewport.

`1vw` - retorna 1% da **largura** do viewport 
`1vh` - retorna 1% da **altura** do viewport

Como `1vw` representa 1% do tamanho do viewport, fixando o `max-width` em `100vw` a tabela terá 100% do viewport, então você poderia acrescentar essa tag na `.table-responsive`, que ficaria assim:

```
.table-responsive {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Segue exemplo do [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzxx442q/)

Comment: Você testou pelo chrome na versao atualizada (v44)? Embora sua abordagem seja interessante a classe `table-responsive` normalmente é utilizada de forma bem genérica e deve respeitar a largura do elemento pai que nem sempre (no meu caso nunca) é o tamanho do viewport...

Comment: Testei, não apresentou o erro para mim, funcionou?

Comment: Você precisa redimensionar a tela até acontecer o problema. O chrome se comporta corretamente até certo ponto... =)

Answer (score -2):

Da uma olha nesse link e ve se te ajuda:

http://leomiranda.com/desenvolvimento/10-controlando-quebras-de-linhas-pelo-css

os seus `<td>` estão por padrão com o inicial, porém isso não faz modo on ele  reajusta a tabela de acordo com o tamanho da página.

caso o link quebre:

aqui esta a explicação

#### Tag White-Space

A primeira é a responsável pelo tratamento dos espaços em brancos, a tag White-Space, essa tag pode ser usada da seguinte forma:

Valor   Descrição
normal  Os espaços em branco serão ignorados pelo browser.
nowrap  O texto será apresentado todo ele numa linha única na tela. Não há quebra de linha até ser encontrada uma tag `<br>`
pre Os espaços em branco serão preservados pelo browser.
pre-line    Os espaços em branco serão ignorados pelo browser e o texto será quebrado quando necessário.
pre-wrap    Os espaços em branco serão preservados pelo browser e o texto será quebrado quando necessário.
inherit Será herdado as características do elemento pai.

O melhor mesmo é testar e ver os resultados. Exemplo de uso:

```
{codecitation}elemento { white-space: normal; }{/codecitation}
```

#### Tag Display

Outra forma interessante de manipular a quebra de linha ou não de um elemento é utilizar a tag display. Quando usamos a tag div percebemos que automaticamente há uma quebra de linha enquanto um span não acontece. Podemos dizer que na tag div está incluso a propriedade display: block enquanto a span está o display: in-line.

```
{codecitation}elemento { display: block; // quebra de linha }

elemento { display: inline; // sem quebra de linha }{/codecitation}
```

Comment: Tem um link para o JSFiddle. Adicionar diretamente na pergunta não vai esclarecer nada, pois é apenas o código da tabela com estilos básicos. Apenas iria poluir a mesma...

Comment: Vi o link do codigo, sorry. Seu problema é que em sua pagina os <td> nao quebram a linha correto?

Comment: o comando <white-space: nowrap> – não quebra linha de jeito nenhum.
para permitir quebra de linha voce pode usar <white-space: nowrap:pre>

Comment: Estou utilizando `white-space: nowrap` apenas no header. Todas as `td`s do corpo da tabela estão com o valor inicial.

Comment: beleza que bom que ajudou.